# Library for image zoom with text?

Tags: javascript, css, zooming

I am trying to find a similar effect as on http://www.solidfloor.com (scroll down a little to the images). I only found normal image zooms, but none with the text and zoom together. Maybe this is a lib which I just not stumbled upon?

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CSS transform` to `scale` the image and adjust the `child text tags` on `hover`. You do not have to use libraries, let alone javascript to achieve this.

This question may get closed the way it is, so rephrase the question and I can assist in solving